# returning wrong values for a simple project

Tags: c++

i have been working on a problem for a programming practice website, i have already solved this in ruby and easily returned correct values, the problem is to find the largest palindromic number that can be yielded from the multiplication of three digit numbers, my code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int h = 0;                                      //this will hold the largest palindrome
    for (int a = 101; a < 1000; a++)                //will cycle through all three digit numbers
    {
        for (int b = 101; b < 1000; b++)            //will cycle through all three digit numbers
        {
            if (a*b%10 != 0)                        //checks to make sure last digit is not zero
            {
                int c = a*b;                        //temporary int to hold value when it is read into an array
                int d[8] = {0};                     //array to hold individual place values
                int e = 0;                          //length of number
                int f = 0;                          //will be used to trace through array
                bool g = true;                      //bool to decide whether or not a number is a palindrome
                while (c > 0)                       //until all digits have been read
                {
                    d[e] = c%10;                    //reads last digit
                    c/=10;                          //chops off last digit
                    e++;                            //grows by on for every exponent of ten
                }
                for (e; e >= f; f++)
                    if (d[f] != d[e-f])             //compares array symetrically
                        g = false;                  //if a difference is found the bool is set to false
                if (g==true)
                    h = a*b;                        //if g remains true then a new value is saved to h.
            }
        }
    }
    cout << h;
    return 0;
}
```

I have commented it to make it easier to read, from my error checking i have determined with almost absolute certainty that the problem lies in these lines

```
     for (e; e >= f; f++)
                if (d[f] != d[e-f])             //compares array symetrically
                    g = false;                  //if a difference is found the bool is set to false
```

somehow my palindromic test does not work as it should, the value returned by this program is 0, it should be  906609

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `e` starts off one value too high, and you're incrementing `f` too many times.

```
            for (e--; e >= f; f++)
            {
                if (d[f] != d[e-f])
                    g = false;
            }
```

Comment: thank you, that fixed my palindromic catch, after i changed if (g==true) to if (g==true && h < a*b) i returned the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Your incrementing f twice - once in the for loop and once at the end of your block statement. Get rid of the last `f++;` in your statement.

Comment: good catch, i fixed that but am still returning 0, the double incrementation of f would have allowed half palindromes to make it through (ex 12151) but would not be the cause of g always turning false.